# How can I count all category under productId?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

So I'm still new using MongoDB, so what I'm trying to do here is **count all** `category` under `productId` who have same category. So the expected output should be `7`. I used populate first but got stuck on how can I use the `$count`. Instead I use `aggregate` and then use `$lookup`, but i only empty array of `product`

CartSchema.js

```
const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}
})

export default mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema)
```

ProductSchema.js

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: {type: String, required: true},

})

export default mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

I used this code to show the information under `productId`.

```
router.get('/categories', async (req, res) => {
    
  try {
    const cart = await Cart.find()
    .populate([
      {path: 'productId', select: 'category' },
    ]).exec()
    res.status(200).json(cart);     

  } catch (error) { 
    res.status(500).json({error: error.message})
  }
})
```

The result of populate method.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "63b410fdde61a124ffd95a51",
        "productId": {
            "_id": "63b410d6de61a124ffd9585b",
            "category": "CASE"
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "63b41a679950cb7c5293bf12",
        "productId": {
            "_id": "63b41637e3957a541eb59e81",
            "category": "CASE"
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "63b433ef226742ae6b30b991",
        "productId": {
            "_id": "63b41637e3957a541eb59e81",
            "category": "CASE"
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "63b670dc62b0f91ee4f8fbd9",
        "productId": {
            "_id": "63b410d6de61a124ffd9585b",
            "category": "CASE"
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "63b6710b62b0f91ee4f8fc13",
        "productId": {
            "_id": "63b410d6de61a124ffd9585b",
            "category": "CASE"
        },

    },
    {
        "_id": "63b671bc62b0f91ee4f8fc49",
        "productId": {
            "_id": "63b410d6de61a124ffd9585b",
            "category": "CASE"
        },
    },
    {
        "_id": "63b6721c62b0f91ee4f8fcc5",
        "productId": {
            "_id": "63b410d6de61a124ffd9585b",
            "category": "CASE"
        },
    ]
```

So I used this method, but instead, I just get an empty array

```
router.get('/categories', async (req, res) => {



 try {
    const cart = await Cart.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'product',
          localField: 'productId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'product'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$product"
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$product.category",
          total: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: {total: -1}
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          category: "$_id",
          total: 1
        }
      },
    

    ])
    res.status(200).json(cart);     

  } catch (error) { 
    res.status(500).json({error: error.message})
  }
})
```

Comment: The Product collection will actually be named `products` (with an `s`) so try changing that in the `from` property of your `$lookup` stage. Other than that the aggregation looks good to me at a glance.

Comment: thanks @Aurast! It works, but can I have the reason why do I need to add the `s` in `product`. Is there any specific rule on that?

Comment: Added the details in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the aggregation, the collection to perform the `$lookup` on should be `products` (with an `s`) rather than `product`.

The name of the collection that Mongoose creates in your database is the same as the name of your model, except lowercase and pluralized, as documented in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html).

> **Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name.** Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the **tanks** collection in the database.

(emphasis theirs)

When using the aggregation framework, your aggregation pipeline is sent to the database as-is. Mongoose doesn't do any sort of coercion or casting on it. So when writing aggregation pipelines you should more or less forget you're using Mongoose. What's important is the name of the underlying collection in Mongo, which is generated from your model name based on the mentioned rule.

You can also override the collection name yourself if desired, for example:

```js
export default mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema, 'xyz');
```

This will override Mongoose's default naming behavior and will name the collection `xyz`.